# Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 Android 4.4.4: TextView Html.fromHtml does not work

Tags: android, textview, spanned

I have this code to show green feedback stars in a TextView:

```
Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#00dd00\">★</font>");
tv.setText(sp);
```

and it works on all devices I've tested beside the one in topic.

I cannot understand why.

A big problem is that the device is not mine and I don't know when I can get it back to test again, so I cannot reproduce the bug.

Another problem is that I've tested a couple of emulators with Android 4.4.4 and I could not find any problem.

Is there another way to show colored text in a safer way ?
Of course the stars are 5 and can be colored in a dynamic way (gray or green) otherwise it would not be a problem.

To be more detailed: if there are 2 green stars, the code is

```
Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#00dd00\">★</font><font color=\"#00dd00\">★</font>");
tv.setText(sp);
```

because it's created in a loop where `<font color=\"#00dd00\">★</font>` is a constant.

**edit:**

This is the definition of the TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtThumbnail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="@dimen/elv_group_thumbnail_text_size"/>
```

"`It does not work`" means that the stars are shown but not green so it seems that the html `color` tag has no effect.

Comment: Please explain, precisely, what "does not work" means. Is the star replaced by some other character? Is the star there, but not in green? Does the app crash?

Comment: Right, sorry: The _not green_  constant is `<font color="#999999">★</font>` and this is what is shown, just gray stars. So the html color tag `#00dd00` does not work.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I realized that the previous comment does not explain, but I was exhausted. I edited the question adding some detail.

Comment: Samsung must have fiddled with `fromHtml()` or something. Why not set the green color on the `TextView`?

Comment: @CommonsWare: because the `TextView` contains 5 stars and 0 to 5 can be green depending on the feedback value. If I set the color to green, all 5 are always green. Well, thanks, I'll find a solution. Probably 5 little `TextView`... I don't like it but, as far, it's the only idea I have.

Comment: Use [a `RatingBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html).

Comment: Yours could be an answer as I asked also for an alternative. Thanks, I'll check it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, suggested by @CommonsWare, is to replace the TextView with a [RatingBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html)

I had to create my own *star pictures* and a `selector` to handle them but, at the end, all is much simpler.
The proof is that I had to delete code :)

I don't know if this works on the Samsung device as well but I don't think that Samsung has fiddled also with the `RatingBar`.
As soon as I get the device, I test and post the result but, as far, this is an acceptable solution from my side.